# Почему 2 раза используется команда вывода?

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, но почему тут используется команда вывода после цикла? мы ведь уже в самом цикле ее указали...

```
for (int i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: У вас после вывода в цикле перенос строки. Вы в следующий раз просто попробуйте удалить код и посмотреть на разницу.

Comment: Вопрос "почему тут используется команда вывода" надо задавать тому, кто этот код написал. Откуда мы знаем, что у него в голове было?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.out.println()` - в данном случае перенос строки, т.к. после `println` операции будут производится на след. строке(аналогично `System.out.print("\n")`).

Про консольный ввод вывод:
[Metanit](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/2.9.php).

Про отличия print от println: [JavaRush](https://javarush.ru/quests/lectures/questsyntax.level01.lecture07).

Answer (score 2):

В цикле используется команда print(), которая записывает значения в одну строку, а после цикла автор переносит курсор на новую строку, используя команду println()

Answer (score 1):

Походу, это так лихо перевод строки организовали. Почитайте про отличия print и println